# How to get Xpath for the following?

Tags: xpath

I have a xml file like following

```
<topic>
    <title>Abstract
    </title>
    <body>
        <p>
            abstract data
        </p>
    </body>
</topic>
<topic>
    <title>Keywords</title>
    <body>
        <p>
            keywords data
        </p>
    </body>
</topic>
```

I have to check if title is "Keywords" than show the `<p>text in </p>`.
can anyone help me to get the exact `xpath` for this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one and let me know the result:

```
//title[text()="Keywords"]/following::p
```

or

```
//topic[title[text()="Keywords"]]//p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below `xpath`

```
//title[text()="Keywords"]/following::p
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Start your `xpath` with `<title>` along with `text` method and move ahead to the `<p>` tag using the `following` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
//title[text()="Keywords"]/body/p
```

for text only

```
//title[text()="Keywords"]/body/p/text()
```

please avoid double slash "//" and following, it will  travel all the **P** tag